# Observed Task Exception calling TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

My App is .NET 4.5 and I have a event handler that logs all error on unobserved task exceptions.

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, e) => e.Exception.Handle(ex =>
{
    logger.Error(e.Exception);
    return false;
});
```

I return false, what shuts down the application. Simulating the .NET 4.0 behavior.

My question is, why this code calls the event and consequently crash my app if I am observing the result?

```
try
{
    var resultado = httpClient.GetAsync('http://.....').Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error(ex);
}
```

**UPDATE:** After some debugging, I figure out that I had another Task when I didn´t called .Result and was causing the problem.

Comment: You are reading the event wrong. It doesn't mean "Exception of an unobserved task" but "Unobserved exception of a task".

Comment: I edited my question. I actually "Get" the exception, to log. When I call Result, it should throw a exception synchronously

Comment: I took the liberty to set a more precise title. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Actually the problem isn´t with TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException. Because I don´t set the exception as Observed there. TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException should never be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I figure out that I had another Task when I didn´t called .Result and  was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to set `UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.Observed` to true. Observing the result at this point has no effect, although one might reasonably believe that it does.